# Snowflake - Network Policy with Stitch best practice?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, stitch

I know that Snowflake [requires a network policy for Stitch](https://www.stitchdata.com/docs/destinations/snowflake/connecting-a-snowflake-data-warehouse-to-stitch#whitelist-stitch-ips) to access a database. I also know that I have to add my own IP address to that network policy to access the data. What's the best way to manage this going forward? I'm thinking of events like my IP address changing or adding new users. Here are the options I can think of:

1. Just keep [adding and updating IP addresses on the network policy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-network-policy.html)
2. Create a different network policy to apply for users that allows access from any IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one network policy for users who will be admins so that any changes required would need to be updated only to the specific sub-set and another one for users who will need to be added as they are on-boarded.
It all would come down to manageability of one or more policies. Please note that only 1 network policy can be attached at the account level.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I have to have an account-level policy for the Stitch connector, or could that just be a user-level policy attached to the Stitch user?